# Python - create several CSV files

Tags: python, csv

let's assume I have some code which creates some data, which I want to put in a csv-file. Therefore I'm using "to_csv". Now, I want to run the code several times, and want to have several csv files.

```
for i in xrange(1000):
     code
     to_csv("csv[i].csv")
```

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `pandas`. You simply use string formatting to generate a different file name.

```
for i in xrange(1000):  # should be xrange, not xrang
     # code
     df.to_csv('csv{}.csv'.format(i))
```